# Pass FileName as argument to .exe file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .exe app that is built using C# and WinForms.  I have a registry entry that allows me to right click on files, and then select the .exe to run that file.  My question is - how can I pass the filename of the selected file to the .exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the variable `%L` in your registry entry as argument to your program.

For example:

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\yourcommand\command] @="Path\To\Your\App.exe \"%L\""